# Is it possible to capture traffic between processes on localhost

Tags: java, localhost, fiddler, network-traffic

I have a servlet that initiates a JDBC call via Type4 driver (*jdbc:db2://localhost:50000*).

I'm using Fiddler to capture traffic and I'm able to capture the request and response to the servlet but I'm not able to fetch any communication between the java program and database.

Is it possible to do it with Fiddler? If not then how else?

Comment: wireshark is the tool you would want to use.

Comment: Did Wireshark start capturing localhost traffic at some point?

Answer (score 2):

Fiddler is a HTTP/HTTPS proxy. Is your Java program using HTTP(S) to communicate with the database? If not, then Fiddler cannot help you with that task.